# add names to objects based on object value

Tags: javascript, object

I am generating a JavaScript object based on a CSV file that I have.

Here is what the object currently looks like-- an array of objects:

```
     [
        {
        "country": "afghanistan",
        "iso3": "afg",
        "first_characteristic": 3,
        "second_characteristic": 5,
        "third_characteristic": 3
        },
        {
        "country": "united states",
        "iso3": "usa",
        "first_characteristic": 8,
        "second_characteristic": 6,
        "third_characteristic": 7
        },
        {
        "country": "china",
        "iso3": "chn",
        "first_characteristic": 6,
        "second_characteristic": 0.7,
        "third_characteristic": 2
        }
    ]
```

[The fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/mL5me2wv/1/).

I'd like to add a name to each object, that is derived from one of its values, and for the output to be a nested object.

So this is what I want the new object to look like:

```
    {
        "afg":{
        "country": "afghanistan",
        "iso3": "afg",
        "first_indicator": 3,
        "second_indicator": 5,
        "third_indicator": 3
        },
        "usa":{
        "country": "united states",
        "iso3": "usa",
        "first_indicator": 8,
        "second_indicator": 6,
        "third_indicator": 7
        },
        "chn":{
        "country": "china",
        "iso3": "chn",
        "first_indicator": 6,
        "second_indicator": 0.7,
        "third_indicator": 2
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out how to add these names. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note `[foo: bar, fizz: buzz]` is not a valid _Array_ in _JavaScript_. Are you saying you want both indices and keys? just keys? just indicies but labels somehow attached?

Comment: Your target json looks incorrect as each element of the array is of the form `"...": {...}`. Is there any need for it to be an array, could it be an object?

Comment: What have you tried so far to convert the object? Can you share an attempt you've made or started on? Or, detail a guess of how you think it might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line using ES6, where `arr` is your data as an *Array* and `obj` is the resulting *Object*

```
var obj = arr.reduce((o, e) => ((o[e.iso3] = e), o), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function setNameToJSONObj(json){

  var rslt = [];

  for(var i = 0; i< json.length; i++){
    rslt[json[i].iso3] = json[i];
  }
  return rslt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also helpful!